# iMessage hacking

Tags: iphone, ipad, messages

I recently found a rather romantic exchange on my boyfriend's iPad.  He insists that he does not have any record of this exchange on his iPhone (which is linked to his iPad) nor does he know the phone number that sent the messages.  The iPad has the other person initiating the conversation and his responses.  Is it possible that he was hacked, or is he simply lying?

How Imessages come up on the phone bill? As texts oor data/emails?

Comment: ..guess he forgot to erase that copy ;)

Comment: Probably given the necessary time and resources just about anything can be hacked however the odds in this case, well lets just say... your boyfriend is cheating on you!

Comment: So he didn't know who the person sending the message was but got into a conversation anyway? Hmmm... what @user3439894 said.

Comment: Couldn't you have just checked who the sender was when you found the conversation on the iPad? Also, your question is not clear about what you are looking for? Do you want to know if the iPad was hacked? 99.99999% - NO.

Answer (score -2):

The devices are connected with iCloud, so if you receive a message on iPhone, the same message appears on iPad. They are synchronised... but they are synchronised by a **COPY**. If you remove a message from one device, it still exists on other devices. And deletions are permanent for a device (iPad, iPod, iPhone). So, he forgot to erase the copy. But is not the same with contacts, or calendar. Removing event, or contact from one device will cause the same action for another devices. They are synchronised fully.

About messages, they are synchronised only when receiving or sending messages, not when removing.

So, there is a hope for you, if your boyfriend has a MacBook too. :-) They are not removed permanently from MacBook. Just send to that person any message from another device. Then a whole thread will be restored on his MacBook :-) If it happens then you are sure - he is lying.

It is impossible for an iPhone/iPad to be hacked by someone else.

Comment: It is not impossible for an iPhone or iPad to be hacked. In addition, messages are only stored on Apple's servers for seven days, and messages from that timeframe can only be retrieved if the device was set up on iMessage with the Apple ID in question _prior to the message being sent_, as noted [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/164149/54484). Finally, once messages are deleted from a Mac running Yosemite, they are not retrievable (except possibly through extraordinary means involving data recovery from the device's storage).

Comment: @tubedogg you should test it on macbook. Just create a thread with someone, even with yourself. Then remove thread from macbook, and then from another device, send a message using that thread. Then you see... a whole thread on macbook was retrieved.Did you test it?

Answer (score -2):

Though it is **difficult** to hack an iPad or iPhone, it is **possible** and people are coming up with new and inventive ways to do it more simply. It is also not that difficult to hack someone's iCloud account if you have the chance to get the password and send messages via the iCloud website. It will show up on other devices that are logged into the account as well but not necessarily all of them. Copies generally go to pads and MacBook/iMac/mac mini. Don't automatically assume that he is cheating. Try talking to him about it and if it continues to happen, then move to the next step.